# Apply strsplit to Column of Strings (cellstr)

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to have an Mx1 cell array containing strings in each cell, and split each such string according to the delimiter '/' (say) and have the result outputted to an MxN cell array, where N is the max of the occurrence of '/' over all the split strings?

In my case, the number of occurrences of '/' is uniform (the possibility of non-uniformity is probably the issue in implementing such a function in general, though one could imagine storing NULL values).

Obviously this could be implemented with a loop, calling splitstr M times, but I was hoping for the existence of a vectorized solution.

---

To help clarify.  Suppose we have

C{1,1} = "1string/2string/.../Nstring"

C{2,1} = "1string/2string/.../Nstring"

...

C{M,1} = "1string/2string/.../Nstring"

I want D to be

D{1,1} = "1string" D{1,2} = "2string" ... D{1,N} = "Nstring"

D{2,1} = "1string" D{2,2} = "2string" ... D{2,N} = "Nstring"

...

D{M,1} = "1string" D{M,2} = "2string" ... D{M,N} = "Nstring"

or something roughly equivalent (for instance; the output doesn't need to be a MxN cell array; it could still be an Mx1 cell array, but with each cell being an 1xN (or Nx1) array with the cells being the split strings).

---

Here is my current implementation (but with M and N instead of C and D; sorry for the confusion).

```
M = strtok(textscan(iID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', ',', 'HeaderLines', 1){1,1}, '"');
% note that strtok will return a cell array of size TOTAL_ROWS x 1
N = cell(length(M), 3);
for i = 1:length(M)
  N(i,:) = strsplit(M{i,1}, '/');
endfor
```

Since the file is gigantic, I'd like to find a vectorized solution if there is one.

Comment: Try using `textscan` with both delimiters, `,` and `/`

Comment: Thanks - I forgot textscan works on strings too

Answer (score 3):

You could do it using [`regexp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) with the `'split'` modifier:

```
D = regexp(C, '/', 'split');
```

This gives an *M*x1 cell array of 1x*N* cell arrays. If you want to collapse that into an *M*x*N* cell array, use

```
D = vertcat(D{:});
```